# Input time [type= time] setting value

Tags: javascript, html

Hoe to set up a value, to input type = time , set in html using value attribute **value**.

I have tried:

```
var tm =  new Date();

var in= "<input type='time' name='time' id='tm' value='" + tm + "'/>";
```

it does not work

Comment: javascript, I'm assuming? What makes you think you can simply stuff a JS **OBJECT** into a string that happens to contain an html input definition?

Comment: what is a proper way to do it? That an easy way to convert an object to string, will automatically call `toString()` for that particular object.

Comment: yes, but how is the JS engine to know how to format that stringified date? `yyyy-mm-dd`? `dd-mm-yy`? unix timestamp? read up on the JS Date object ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [valueAsDate](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#time-state-%28type=time%29) attribute to convert between a `Date` object and an input element’s value.

```
> var elem = document.createElement('input');
> elem.type = 'time';
> elem.valueAsDate = new Date(1970, 1, 1, 7, 34);
> elem.value
"12:34"
```

Comment: Anyway to pass a string like `11:30am`?

Comment: Yes you can pass in any valid RFC 3339 time string to elem.value - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html