# how to set hours only of an input type time dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to set the value of an input type time dynamically one by one i.e first hours then minutes then am/pm.

For example `<input type="time"/>` gives -- :-- -- 
I have another component called dial pad that contains numbers. In that if user clicks on the number then i want to send that number to the input as hours and display it in the input time like this
01:-- --

then once the Hour input is filled move to the min like this

01:12 AM

How to achieve this in javascript or react js.
**This is not a duplicate.** In the link [Input time [type= time] setting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718832/input-time-type-time-setting-value) it sets with whole date object like this

```
elem.valueAsDate = new Date(1970, 1, 1, 7, 34);
```

and the input will be whole value like 12:12 PM

but i want only hours to be filled first example 12:-- --.
In simple words i want to display 12:-- -- in input type time dynamically.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. I think you should add some code and explain your question better.

Comment: Hi mmgross , I just edited my question please read it agin.

Comment: Use multiple inputs. Give it a parent node with a helpful class name. Write a wrapper for accessing it.

Comment: Hi Paul If you could please provide me a code then that will be much helpful for me as i am not a java script developer.