# how to set default value for input type time

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to set a default time for the time input?

I've tried the following but no time is showing on the UI:

```
                <Input
                  value={new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}
                  type="time"
                  id="time"
                  {...form.register("time")}
                />
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#time_value_format says the value should be a 24h time string like `14:00`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input time \[type= time\] setting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718832/input-time-type-time-setting-value)

Comment: @Kaddath toString() expects 0 arguments but got 1

Comment: May you [check the linked question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718832/input-time-type-time-setting-value). It uses a `valueAsDate` which I think is more suitable.

Comment: @Kaddath ... of cause not ... the `toString` method does not recognize any parameters.

Comment: Sorry guys I always forget we monkey patch `toString` where I work, it is so much easier I tend to forget it's not regular JS :D

Answer (score 0):

Got it, the following works:

```
                <Input
                  value={new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0]}
                  type="time"
                  id="time"
                  {...form.register("time")}
                />
```